# Showing Tabs at Bottom in Android using titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I have a requirement in which i have to show TABS which we are using to navigate, To show TAB at bottom.
When i am running my application on device , On android its showing at Top while in I-Phone it is showing at the Bottom.
So anyone can guide me how to show Tabs specifically for android At the bottom of the screen

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: Have a look at this link:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130731/howto-move-the-android-tabbar-to-the-bottom It change the style of all the tabbar in the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had to do this, and after a lot of search, we concluded that it is not possible simply using titanium appcelerator. We chose to do this by implementing a button bar at the bottom of our window.

When I searched right now however, I have found a few others have tried to solve this problem in other ways.

1. [Display tab bar in bottom in Android](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/113921/want-to-display-tab-bar-in-bottom)
2. [Custom tab bar for iphone and android](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/46801/giving-to-the-community-custom-tabgroup-class-working-on-android-and-iphone)

Comment: No its not working in Android in Titanium sdk 1.8.1 and give error throw "CustomTabGroup error: This is only supported by iPhone!";

Comment: Hi ,
I have a problem now. this is not working with latest Titanium SDK 3.0.0 or later. can you give me any solution.
I want to My tabbar show in bottom in Android.

Comment: I am not using Titanium anymore. Try looking into their latest documentation. It might also be possible that native Android has stopped supporting tabs. Please check that too.

Comment: Url links has been removed.
Wastage of time.

Comment: @PradeepYaduvanshy  Perhaps, they were removed from titanium forums. For me, however, the links were automatically redirected to their archive. I don't know why redirection didn't work for you. I have now updated these links accordingly.

Comment: You are right bro.
Removed from titanium forum.
So for  now its wastage of time.
Thanks for your efforts.